# Can't use console.log()

Tags: javascript, firebase, console.log

Here I am, having trouble to figure out how to use the `console.log()` function in order to debug a javascript program.
To be concrete, the code hereafter is working and displays data in the web browser as expected, using `document.write()`.

The problem concerns the lines using `console.log()` I have looked in every place I could think of and also tried to find the info on google, but to no avail.
I cannot find any trace of the messages I expect to be printed by `console.log()`.

I must obviously be looking in the wrong place or doing something wrong. Any relevant tip will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

var dbURL = "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/MyThings/",
dbRef = new Firebase(dbURL);

dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  console.log("The read SUCCEDED!");
  document.write("MyThings<br/>\n");

  for (element in snapshot.val()) {
    document.write("Hello " + element + " :<br/>\n");
  }
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I must obviously be looking in the wrong place"* - Where are you looking? In most browsers, pressing F12 brings up the dev tools, and then the console is one of the tabs in the dev tools window.

Comment: Not 100% the same cross browser but [chrome dev tools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) should be a big help and nuances aside dev tools are similar cross browser

Comment: Also note you can't use `document.write()` in asynchronous code after page has loaded...it wipes out the whole page!

Comment: Yes indeed F12 works on my Linux machine. I go through a different path on my Mac. Anyway, I had found that, but I see no message there. I only see (in the JS tab) "The connection to wss://s-usclc-nss....was interrupted while loading"

Comment: [Here's a gif that shows opening the devtools](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/javascript-console.gif)

Comment: OK. I can open devtools, but even when opened there is still no message appearing.

Answer (score 0):

i think the event is not get triggered 
you can try to  catch the errors and log them

Comment: But the question seems to be saying that the document.write() calls work.

Comment: But why isn't it triggered. And YES document.write() is working.